# Installing libcheck in fedora 26 but fails to link

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, fedora-26

I use libcheck in my C code for testing. I installed it using RPM (current version). In the folder /usr/lib64 i can find libcheck.so.0 and libsubunit.so.0. I did encounter however the following problems:

- The header file was not in /usr/include, i copied it there myself
- I'm not able to link the library using -lcheck of using -
  L/user/lib64/libcheck.so.0

i'm not sure if i did something wrong during the installation or why this is going so terribly. Any advice?

Comment: What about using "`-L/usr/lib64`" instead of "`- L/user/lib64/libcheck.so.0`"

Comment: no success, undefined reference to the functions but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the `check-devel` package in addition to `check`.  It contains both the header file in `/usr/include` and the `.so` library file which enables linking.

This is documented in various places, for example in the [packaging guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Devel_Packages).

Comment: Thanks, you save my day! Way is this not documented better?